# box-shadow property is not working if used with transition in IE and Edge

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why `box-shadow` property is not working when used in combination with `transition` in IE and Edge. Though, these properties do work in any other browser without any issue. But really can't figure out what's the issue in regards to only IE and Edge.

Here's my code in action:

```css
.tb_records {
  width:700px;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
}

.tb_records th, .tb_records td {
  padding:15px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
}

.tb_records tr {
  -webkit-transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}

.tb_records tr:not(:first-child):hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.tb_records tr td:first-child {
  border-left:3px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition:border-left 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition:border-left 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition:border-left 0.3s linear;
  transition:border-left 0.3s linear;
}

.tb_records tr:hover td:first-child {
  border-left:3px solid #4285F4;
}

.tb_records tr td:last-child {
  border-right:3px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition:border-right 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition:border-right 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition:border-right 0.3s linear;
  transition:border-right 0.3s linear;
}

.tb_records tr:hover td:last-child {
  border-right:3px solid #4285F4;
}
```

```html
<table class="tb_records">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Phone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alan</td>
    <td>Bowers</td>
    <td>ban@gmail.com</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ben</td>
    <td>Oliver</td>
    <td>ben@gmail.com</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Chris</td>
    <td>Armes</td>
    <td>chris@gmail.com</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paul</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>peb@yahoo.com</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sagar</td>
    <td>Soni</td>
    <td>sag@yahoo.co.uk</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think this is more of an issue with IE not supporting `box-shadow` on tables when the border-collapse is set to collapse. See the "Known Issues" tab [on this page](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) - "_Edge and IE up to 11 suppress box-shadow in tables with border-collapse:collapse._". As a test, set `border-collapse:separate` on your table and you should see the shadow

Comment: @zgood you might be right but I can't use `separate` instead of `collapse` as it screws up my design. Moreover the `box-shadow` turns out to be very ugly. No benefit at all indeed!

Comment: I understand. I am just letting you know the problem is not with `transition` but with `box-shadow` on tables. IE just doesn't support that. Can you change your table markup?

Comment: This works for me the exact same in Edge as it does in Firefox. As for IE, don't try to support that, because it's a dead browser. Likewise you probably don't need those -o- prefixes for Opera, either.

Comment: @TylerH doesn't work for me in Edge. You on some dev or beta channel?

Comment: @zgood No, Edge v80. But it works for me in pre-Chromium Edge as well.

Comment: @zgood thanks for letting me know about that bug. But now I am realizing that we can't fix it anyhow. And oh! I really can't change my HTML markup as it results in a big tedious task for me and may not be feasible.

Comment: Well you could try changing the display of your table rows to something like `display: flex; width: 100%;`, then it might work because its no longer a `display:table-row` and that bug wouldn't be there. But that could create other problems also I dunno

Answer (score 0):

Add -ms-box-shadow to the code. That may work Box-Shadow does seem supported in IE11.

```css
.tb_records {
  width:700px;
  margin:50px auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
}

.tb_records th, .tb_records td {
  padding:15px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #dddddd;
}

.tb_records tr {
  -webkit-transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
  transition:box-shadow 0.5s linear;
}

.tb_records tr:not(:first-child):hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -moz-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -ms-box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow:0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.tb_records tr td:first-child {
  border-left:3px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition:border-left 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition:border-left 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition:border-left 0.3s linear;
  transition:border-left 0.3s linear;
}

.tb_records tr:hover td:first-child {
  border-left:3px solid #4285F4;
}

.tb_records tr td:last-child {
  border-right:3px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition:border-right 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition:border-right 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition:border-right 0.3s linear;
  transition:border-right 0.3s linear;
}

.tb_records tr:hover td:last-child {
  border-right:3px solid #4285F4;
}
```

```html
<table class="tb_records">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Phone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alan</td>
    <td>Bowers</td>
    <td>ban@gmail.com</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ben</td>
    <td>Oliver</td>
    <td>ben@gmail.com</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Chris</td>
    <td>Armes</td>
    <td>chris@gmail.com</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paul</td>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>peb@yahoo.com</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sagar</td>
    <td>Soni</td>
    <td>sag@yahoo.co.uk</td>
    <td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you ever seriously try yourself?